# C# Шифрование строки со всегда разным результатом

Tags: c#, криптография, шифрование, aes

Необходимо зашифровать строку таким образом, чтобы по одному и тому же ключу получался всегда разный результат. В AES алгоритмах для этого можно использовать разный вектор, но для дешифровки, помимо ключа, нужно знать этот вектор. Мне необходимо получать уникальное зашифрованное сообщение только по ключу. Какие алгоритмы я могу использовать для этого?

Comment: А варианты ответов есть?

Comment: @aepot если бы я знал варианты, то этого вопроса бы не было)

Comment: Что мешает записать вектор к данным, например в начало? Будет один и тот же ключ, и всегда разный вывод, то что надо.

Comment: @aepot можно и так, но хотелось бы алгоритм, который не требует таскать вектор вместе с результатом

Comment: Я дал ответ, в любом случае если вас результат устраивает, то рекомендую использовать именно этот способ, так как он надежнее любого своего собственного веслосипеда. К тому же можете подключить NuGet Bouncy Castle и выбрать любой модный алгоритм.

Comment: @aepot так и сделаю, не буду изобретать велосипед. Спасибо

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Я бы сделал как-то так, по сути результат тот, что соответствует вашему условию.

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string text = "Hello World!";
    byte[] key = Enumerable.Range(0, 32).Select(x => (byte)x).ToArray();
    Console.WriteLine(Encrypt(text, key));
    Console.WriteLine(Encrypt(text, key));
    Console.WriteLine(Encrypt(text, key));
    Console.WriteLine(Encrypt(text, key));
    string base64 = Encrypt(text, key);
    Console.WriteLine(base64);
    Console.WriteLine(Decrypt(base64, key));
    Console.ReadKey();
}

private static string Encrypt(string text, byte[] key)
{
    using Aes aes = Aes.Create();
    aes.Key = key;
    using MemoryStream ms = new();
    ms.Write(aes.IV);
    using (CryptoStream cs = new(ms, aes.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write, true))
    {
        cs.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text));
    }
    return Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
}

private static string Decrypt(string base64, byte[] key)
{
    using MemoryStream ms = new(Convert.FromBase64String(base64));
    byte[] iv = new byte[16];
    ms.Read(iv);
    using Aes aes = Aes.Create();
    aes.Key = key;
    aes.IV = iv;
    using CryptoStream cs = new(ms, aes.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read, true);
    using MemoryStream output = new();
    cs.CopyTo(output);
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(output.ToArray());
}
```

Вывод в консоль

```
130gYdJGjVNVWeCp8ep8kLlyX39fg1nY4vl99wNIYIw=
TstMTm9mvyjiO9nM2M8sdoYLktkpmMRolhGYGPCbwpM=
HGM8CIiXaBpluZdBBggR2yXXeGpDTMkLi/OreZQWPnE=
/sE0aIsc0wkcc3kP3df9TWPRBt/2/OKSd1eAORSBCOc=
Kd6JMwFkMRae1sgjEks76j7+kfRR1Lb3Vz3NVj7DeRw=
Hello World!
```

Всегда разный вывод с одним и тем же ключом, потому что `Aes` генерирует рандомный `IV` каждый раз.

Comment: Магия какая-то! - показалось на первый взгляд. Полез разбираться. Ага, понятно. Здорово!

Comment: Пытался использовать ваш код, но получаю `CryptographicException: Specified key is not a valid size for this algorithm`. Ключ получаю так: `byte[] key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("AAAAAAAAAAAAAA")`

Comment: @GoodBoyAlex ключ потому что это не пароль. Ключ в данном случае это набор из ровно 32 байт. Я прилинковал к вашему вопросу 2 ответа, используйте код из второго, там как раз показано как сделать ключ из пароля. `using Rfc2898DeriveBytes hasher = new(password, sa.IV, 1000, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256); byte[] key = hasher.GetBytes(32);` где `password` - ваш пароль.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Однако же столкнулся с другой ошибкой: `FormatException: The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters`.

Comment: @GoodBoyAlex задайте отдельный вопрос, приведите полный воспроизводимый пример.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1538722/Ошибка-formatexception-the-input-is-not-a-valid-base-64-string-при-шифровке-тек