# Криптография C# AesManager

Tags: c#, winforms, криптография

У меня возник вопрос, я использую `AesManager` для шифрации и дешифрации строки. Условно говоря, строки на выходе это данные которые сохраняются локально. (Проект сам для себя, просто интересна тема)
Так вот, покопавшись в интернете, я собрал вот такое такое чудо

```
private static string EncryptString(string plainText, string password)
    {
        byte[] initialVectorBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(vector);
        byte[] saltValueBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(salt);
        byte[] plainTextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);

        using PasswordDeriveBytes derivedPassword = new(password, saltValueBytes, hash, iterations);
        byte[] keyBytes = derivedPassword.GetBytes(keySize / 8);
        using AesManaged aes = new();
        aes.Key = keyBytes;
        aes.IV = initialVectorBytes;

        byte[] cipherTextBytes = null;

        using (ICryptoTransform encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor(keyBytes, initialVectorBytes))
        {
            using MemoryStream memStream = new();
            using CryptoStream cryptoStream = new(memStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
            cryptoStream.WriteAsync(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);
            cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();

            cipherTextBytes = memStream.ToArray();
        }

        return Convert.ToBase64String(cipherTextBytes);
    }

    public static string DecryptString(string cipherText, string password)
    {
        byte[] vectorBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(vector);
        byte[] saltValueBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(salt);
        byte[] cipherTextBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);

        using PasswordDeriveBytes passwordDeriv = new(password, saltValueBytes, hash, iterations);
        byte[] keyBytes = passwordDeriv.GetBytes(keySize / 8);
        using AesManaged aes = new();
        aes.Key = keyBytes;
        aes.IV = vectorBytes;

        byte[] plainTextBytes = new byte[cipherTextBytes.Length];
        int byteCount = 0;

        using (ICryptoTransform decryptor = aes.CreateDecryptor(keyBytes, vectorBytes))
        {
            using MemoryStream memStream = new();
            using CryptoStream cryptoStream = new(memStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read);
            byteCount = cryptoStream.Read(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);
        }

        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plainTextBytes, 0, byteCount);
    }
```

Проблема в том, что шифруется строка нормально, но вот при дешифровке выдается пустая строка.

```
iterations = 2;
keySize = 256;

hash = "SHA1";
salt = "acecraa138430d31";
vector = "2367az23cwl87xyu";
```

Все значения рандомные, просто для примера

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил вопрос таким способом

```
private static string EncryptString(string plainText, string password)
    {
        byte[] initialVectorBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_vector);
        byte[] saltValueBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_salt);
        byte[] plainTextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);

        try
        {
            using PasswordDeriveBytes derivedPassword = new(password, saltValueBytes, _hash, _iterations);

            byte[] keyBytes = derivedPassword.GetBytes(_keySize / 8);

            using (AesManaged aes = new() { Key = keyBytes, IV = initialVectorBytes })
            {
                using MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, aes.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write, true))
                {
                    cs.Write(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);
                }
                return Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.Message;
        }
    }

    public static string DecryptString(string cipherText, string password)
    {
        byte[] initialVectorBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_vector);
        byte[] saltValueBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_salt);
        byte[] cipherTextBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);

        try
        {
            using MemoryStream ms = new(cipherTextBytes);
            using PasswordDeriveBytes derivedPassword = new(password, saltValueBytes, _hash, _iterations);

            byte[] keyBytes = derivedPassword.GetBytes(_keySize / 8);

            using (AesManaged aes = new() { Key = keyBytes, IV = initialVectorBytes })
            {
                byte[] plainTextBytes = new byte[cipherTextBytes.Length];
                int byteCount = 0;

                using CryptoStream cs = new(ms, aes.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read, true);
                byteCount = cs.Read(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);

                return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plainTextBytes, 0, byteCount);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Замечений не имею, но пароли не передают в `string`. Потому что этот `string` может жить в памяти приложения сколько угодно долго, и вы не можете этим управлять. К примеру, массив можно обнулить, а строку нельзя.

Comment: [Просто оставлю это здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1209370/373567).

Comment: @aepot спасибо, понял, но я думал то что нужно параметром передавать массив байтов, но не понимал зачем.

Comment: в дополнение к замечанию @aepot [см. здесь](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/java/MSC59-J.+Limit+the+lifetime+of+sensitive+data) и еще, маловато будет итераций, рекомендованное количество итераций что-то типа >64к

Comment: @Barmaley ну тогда есть еще 2 решения: [устаревшее](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.security.securestring?view=netcore-3.1) и [будущее решение](https://github.com/dotnet/designs/pull/147#issuecomment-844392771).

Comment: Я не специалист в dot Net, в Java это [GuardedString](https://docs.oracle.com/html/E28160_01/org/identityconnectors/common/security/GuardedString.html)

Comment: @Barmaley Ну из универа я знаю, что SHA1 устарел и больше не используется, сейчас я использую SHA256. А 64к итераций не слишком ли много? Т.е системные ресурсы ведь сжирать дико будет или нет?