# Как получить из RSACryptoServiceProvider (RSAParameters) ключ ввиде наборов байтов

Tags: c#, rsa

Как получить из RSACryptoServiceProvider (RSAParameters) ключ ввиде наборов байтов.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            byte[] data = null;
            byte[] privKey;
            {
                RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(512);
                privKey = rsa.ExportParameters(true).Modulus;
                data = rsa.Encrypt(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hi"), false);
            }
            {
                var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(512);
                var t = rsa.ExportParameters(true);
                t.Modulus = privKey;
                rsa.ImportParameters(t);
                var newD = rsa.Decrypt(data, false); // Not Working
            }
        }
    }
}
```

В этом коде у меня на строке с `rsa.Decrypt` вылетает исключение: `System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: "Присоединенное к системе устройство не работает. "`

Comment: Что этот код должен делать, каково его назначение? Какую задачу вы решаете?

Comment: @aepot Для начало мне просто нужно получить приватный ключ в виде байтов, которое в будущем наверно буду отправлять по сокету или т.п. другому серверу на другом языке

Comment: А чем вас AES шифрование не устраивает? И приватный ключ обычно никуда не отправляется. Отправляется публичный ключ.

Comment: @aepot AES же симметричный, я хотел бы асимметрично

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказываеться для того чтоб передать приватный ключ нужно из RSAParameters:

- Modulus
- D
- P
- Q
- DP
- DQ
- Exponent

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Передавать приватный ключ - это в принципе противоречит концепции ассиметричного шифрования.

Comment: @aepot а если между локальными программами на разных языка, а играеться с PEM и дургими форматами долго

Comment: @МММ DPAPI? AES? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1209370/373567

Comment: @aepot Мне просто из одной языка в другой, а потом второй язык уже будет работать с клиентом например

Comment: Если уж хочется ассиметричного, сделайте нормальный обмен публичными ключами, не выдумывайте велосипедов. Как сделать в одну сторону, я вам уже показал, в обратную делается точно так же. А между процессами на сервере для обмена есть Named Pipes и шифрование там вообще ни к чему. Только ресурсы процессора сливать на него будете.

Comment: @aepot Язык C# с другим языком будет без шифрование общаться, а с шифрованием будет уже клиент из интернета например общаться (пример)

Comment: Ну и шифруйте прямо там, где с клиентом связь идет, а не в недрах сервера.

Comment: В смысле, приватный ключ создавайте каждый раз новый при рукопожатии, не нужно его хранить и передавать. Если у вас прослойка отвечает за шифрование, то пусть она и создает ключи.