# Не работает метод дешифрования C#

Tags: c#, шифрование

Здравствуйте нужно зашифровать данные путей к файлам, использую вот такой метод

```
static public object EncryptData(byte[] data, string password)
    {
        SymmetricAlgorithm sa = null;
        try
        {
            sa = Rijndael.Create();
            ICryptoTransform ct = sa.CreateEncryptor(
                (new PasswordDeriveBytes(password, null)).GetBytes(16),
                new byte[16]);
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, ct, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
            cs.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            cs.FlushFinalBlock();
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return e;
        }
    }
    static public string EncryptDataStr(string data, string password)
    {
        object tmp = EncryptData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data), password);
        if (!(tmp is Exception))
        {
            return Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])tmp);
        }
        else return null;
    }
```

так вот, шифрование работает, но метод дешифрования не работает.
Метод дешифрования

```
static public object DecryptData(byte[] data, string password)
    {
        SymmetricAlgorithm sa = null;
        try
        {
            sa = Rijndael.Create();
            ICryptoTransform ct = sa.CreateDecryptor(
                (new PasswordDeriveBytes(password, null)).GetBytes(16),
                new byte[16]);
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, ct, CryptoStreamMode.Read);
            cs.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
            cs.FlushFinalBlock();
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return e;
        }
    }

    static public string DecryptDataStr(string data, string password)
    {
        object tmp = DecryptData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data), password);
        if (!(tmp is Exception))
        {
            return Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])tmp);
        }
        else return null;
    }
```

Метод дешифровки выдаёт ошибку System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: "Заполнение неверно и не может быть удалено.", в чём может быть проблема?. Я новичок, поэтому прошу прощения если проблема очень лёгкая.

Comment: Похожий вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1209351/373567

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CryptographicException: Заполнение неверно и не может быть удалено.` или на английском `CryptographicException: Padding is invalid and cannot be removed.` означает, что либо ключ шифрования (пароль) неверен, либо баги в коде.

Ну давайте разбираться, выглядит как код, откопанный из 2000-x, здесь устарело всё.

И так:

- `Rijndael` - [дырявое старьё](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rijndael?view=net-6.0), закопайте обратно, есть же `Aes`.
- `PasswordDeriveBytes` - дырявое старьё, закопайте обратно, есть же `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`.
- исключения должен обрабатывать вызывающий код, а не вот это вот всё.
- забыли про Initial Vector (IV)
- забыли про `IDisposable`
- почему-то `DecryptDataStr` ничем не отличается от `EncryptDataStr`. Думаете, если скопировать и переименовать шифрующий метод, он будет расшифровывать? Не будет. Не смутило даже 2 раза `ToBase64String`, а где обратное преобразование `FromBase64String`?

Вот, немного переписал, использую рандомный `IV` и сохраняю его вместе с данными. А так же, чтобы не мудрить, его же использую как соль к паролю. По умолчанию `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` использует хэширование SHA1, которое уже тоже устарело, поэтому заменил на более модный алгоритм SHA256.

*Пусть вас не смущает число `1000`, передаваемое в конструктор, это значение по умолчанию, означающее, сколько раз надо прокрутить пароль через хэш, чтобы получить результат. Просто у `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` нет конструктора, который принимает имя алгоритма хэширования без указания количества итераций.*

```
public static byte[] EncryptData(byte[] data, string password)
{
    using SymmetricAlgorithm sa = Aes.Create();
    using Rfc2898DeriveBytes hasher = new(password, sa.IV, 1000, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256);
    sa.Key = hasher.GetBytes(32);
    using MemoryStream ms = new();
    ms.Write(sa.IV);
    using (CryptoStream cs = new(ms, sa.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
    {
        cs.Write(data);
    }
    return ms.ToArray();
}

public static string EncryptText(string text, string password)
{
    return Convert.ToBase64String(EncryptData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text), password));
}

public static byte[] DecryptData(byte[] data, string password)
{
    using MemoryStream ms = new(data);
    byte[] iv = new byte[16];
    ms.Read(iv);
    using SymmetricAlgorithm sa = Aes.Create();
    using Rfc2898DeriveBytes hasher = new(password, iv, 1000, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256);
    sa.Key = hasher.GetBytes(32);
    sa.IV = iv;
    using CryptoStream cs = new(ms, sa.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read, true);
    using MemoryStream output = new();
    cs.CopyTo(output);
    return output.ToArray();
}

public static string DecryptText(string text, string password)
{
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(DecryptData(Convert.FromBase64String(text), password));
}
```

А вот проверяющий код, обработка исключений здесь

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string text = "Hello World";
    string password = "1234";
    string base64 = null;

    try
    {
        base64 = EncryptText(text, password);
        Console.WriteLine(base64);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Не удалось зашифровать ({ex.GetType().Name}: {ex.Message})");
    }

    try
    {
        string decrypted = DecryptText(base64, password);
        Console.WriteLine(decrypted);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Не удалось расшифровать ({ex.GetType().Name}: {ex.Message})");
    }
}
```

Вывод в консоль

```
Rz7u8DBJeSngbO/D2bvicpfUTfUaHtsZ9zy9RKZg3eQ=
Hello World
```

Кстати, при каждом запуске вывод другой, но всё работает, так и должно быть

```
vJHiX4OctBm0C9QFXB2YaFj4PROTYLbBgky1c9tYuzY=
Hello World
```

А вот что будет, если указать неверный пароль при расшифровке

```
S4O4E5J/cgMAJh7oFK4NhD1Br1W8yc1CelgjB59KD9M=
Не удалось расшифровать (CryptographicException: Padding is invalid and cannot be removed.)
```

Знакомая ошибка?

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо, я очень плохо разбираюсь в теме шифров, вы всё очень подробно расписали, сейчас буду пробовать. Ещё раз огромное спасибо