# Как сравнить два хеша(sh1) с солью на совпадение

Tags: c#, криптография

Вот код создания хеша sh1. Как сравнить два таких хеша на совпадение ?

1. Мой сайт генерирует хеш по несложной формуле(которую описал ниже) с помощью секретного ключа. где key2sfs это и есть секретный ключ
2. Далее этот хеш отправляется на мой сервер.
3. Мой сервер генерирует хеш по той же формуле, используя тот же ключ .
4. Хеши совпали — доступ разрешен, не совпали — запрещен.

   ```
    using System.Security.Cryptography;
    using System.Text;

    //Метод для генерации хеша
    string getHesh()
    {
        int lifetime = 3600 * 3; // The link will become invalid in 3 hours.
        long starttime = DateTimeOffset.Now.ToUnixTimeSeconds() - 300;
        long endtime = starttime + lifetime;
        string salt = Convert.ToHexString(RandomNumberGenerator.GetBytes(16));
        string hash = Hash($"cam_10000760no_check_ip{starttime}{endtime}key2sfs{salt}");
        Console.WriteLine("Хеш: " + hash);
        return hash;
    }

    static string Hash(string input)
    {
        using (SHA1 sha1 = SHA1.Create())
        {
            byte[] hash = sha1.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input));
            return String.Concat(hash.Select(b => b.ToString("x2")));
        }
    }
   ```

Comment: Совпадение чего?

Comment: Хеши совпали или нет

Comment: Имеется входное значение. Генерируется соль. Генерируется хеш. В БД (или где-либо ещё) сохраняются хеш и соль. / При проверке берётся новое входное значение, из БД извлекаются хеш и соль. Снова генерируется хеш по значению и соли. Два хеша сравниваются.

Comment: 2 хэша можно сравнить как 2 строки или как 2 массива, в зависимости от того,как вам удобнее сравнивать, ничего мудрить не надо. Как сравнить 2 строки, надо рассказывать?

Comment: @aepot Ну так соль, то разная в обоих случая

Comment: Нет, соль в обоих случаях одинаковая. Повторю ещё раз: хеш и соль хранятся одновременно.

Comment: Значит вопрос не имеет решения.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov вопрос решен, без передачи соли и вправду никак

Comment: Рекомендую использовать более надежные методы хэширования пароля, например класс `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` + SHA256 https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1445552/373567 соль при этом можно передавать вместе с данными или не использовать вообще.