# Как прочитать соль из файла или пропустить

Tags: c#, aes

Я генерирую Salt рандомную соль и записываю в файл.
Размер соли 32 байта.
Я просто использую соль чтобы читать данные, но мне нужно сделать чтобы либо, соль удалить при чтение и читать дальше или же как-нибудь пропустить.

Подскажите, как вы читаете рандомную соль в файлах?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1445552/373567

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Запись

```
byte[] salt = CreateRandomSalt(); // int[32];
byte[] data = ...;
using var fs = File.Create(path);
fs.Write(salt);
fs.Write(data);
```

Чтение

```
byte[] salt = new int[32];
byte[] data = ...;
using var fs = File.OpenRead(path);
fs.Read(salt);
fs.Read(data);
```

Ничего космически сложного

Answer (score 1):

```
var allBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(file);

byte[] salt = allBytes.Take(32).ToArray();
byte[] data = allBytes.Skip(32).ToArray();
```

Код найден по запросу "c# skip bites file read" в первой ссылке и просто немного доработан под нужды даного вопроса

Comment: Для коротких файлов норм, только bytes (байты) а не bites (укусы).

Comment: @aepot ну я почему-то и подумал что файлы там короткие. Хз почему, сейчас перечитал вопрос - понимаю что о размере файла ничего не написано