# Rsa как расшифровать данные

Tags: c#, rsa

Проблема в расшифровки данных, получаются крякозябры.
Если я хочу в одном приложение написать шифрование данных, а в другом расшифровку данных при помощи RSA-2048, то я должен просто хранить приватный ключ или так же публичный ключ где-то подгружать?
Просто для расшифровки в примере ниже используется переменная которой шифровал текст.

Итак код:
`RSA_Encrypt` - Использую для шифрования текста публичным ключём
`RSA_Decrypt` - Использую для расшифровки текста приватным ключём

```
public static string RSA_Encrypt(string textToEncrypt, string publicKeyString)
{
    byte[] bytesToEncrypt = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(textToEncrypt);
    using RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new(2048);
    try
    {
        rsa.FromXmlString(publicKeyString.ToString());
        byte[] encryptedData = rsa.Encrypt(bytesToEncrypt, true);
        string base64Encrypted = Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedData);
        return base64Encrypted;
    }
    finally
    {
        rsa.PersistKeyInCsp = false;
    }
}

public static string RSA_Decrypt(string textToDecrypt, string privateKeyString)
{
   // byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(textToDecrypt);
    string result;
    using (RSACryptoServiceProvider rsacryptoServiceProvider = new(2048))
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] rgb = Convert.FromBase64String(textToDecrypt);
            rsacryptoServiceProvider.FromXmlString(privateKeyString);    
            byte[] bytes2 = rsacryptoServiceProvider.Decrypt(rgb, true);
            string @string = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes2);
            result = @string.ToString();
        }
        finally
        {
            rsacryptoServiceProvider.PersistKeyInCsp = false;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Важные строчки

```
string keyRSA = RSA_Encrypt("password", File.ReadAllText("PublicKey.xml")); 
string KeyDec = RSA_Decrypt(keyRSA, File.ReadAllText("PrivateKey.xml"));
```

Обычно чтобы расшифровать текст используется переменная keyRSA которым шифровали.
Но, вот допустим я хочу использовать шифрование отдельным приложением, а расшифровку так же отдельным.
То мне по логике нужно записать keyRSA в файл и далее читать его из текста, но если я читаю его из текста, то получается расшифровка криво.
Как правильно расшифровать данные по отдельности (приложений) ???

[**Тестирование**]

**PublicKey.xml**

```xml
<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>xdNofPib4/7be85yyyCAxNGXASigoQDZHWBMQbX+oRP2tNnkxMiRaJ95v1M/OvZhcUNVDXiLsirgtvguWIGBLjpTIU/r5uoKXVFsPFEjLEcQgMS6wILhVgBESI494vEnpVyM/yT3mWy/+KDhmDijDdGezP0/eBydLQBssPlgDOTJTMIGMn4glM1YbQYHdDVEfed6lu16SuAjcQIE+GLHjMSPSxxjC0AqNo5T5n445W/JU2pPiJT4P5ToV6v+2d0L2v4b9jG1cHyCut+qLBWJiDDvproAetIrfBM52nvd/cUrrhLNnd8rN9ICPHXM3jismenmM2bCAbEQg6LaYKJMzQ==</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent></RSAKeyValue>
```

**PrivateKey.xml**

```xml
<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>xdNofPib4/7be85yyyCAxNGXASigoQDZHWBMQbX+oRP2tNnkxMiRaJ95v1M/OvZhcUNVDXiLsirgtvguWIGBLjpTIU/r5uoKXVFsPFEjLEcQgMS6wILhVgBESI494vEnpVyM/yT3mWy/+KDhmDijDdGezP0/eBydLQBssPlgDOTJTMIGMn4glM1YbQYHdDVEfed6lu16SuAjcQIE+GLHjMSPSxxjC0AqNo5T5n445W/JU2pPiJT4P5ToV6v+2d0L2v4b9jG1cHyCut+qLBWJiDDvproAetIrfBM52nvd/cUrrhLNnd8rN9ICPHXM3jismenmM2bCAbEQg6LaYKJMzQ==</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent><P>yfUymvOyzlKIEJJh/ns8IgXJ4CPbV9RgL47GFXf25Eh8/xjSlgNMlab9XS4do7Jg2yPDLurBpCa5JGRTuWyE1F+roMoHbTKPUwDzqSz2Y0QOSbjQFRKRwB+sD9Zmlqh+Xf8Zz+RoUt0bLiDcwFiscK6iOaEcMAk/P3x/zeii3ws=</P><Q>+sMnrBMxPBETYFO3wpuy/kYT/i+wBFicbD3hhdmHet9n3C2Vbo/pX/E+S5fB4HXJYupSll7M7yPInq54kt+KcxfuzvN61vh9GhkCsSkScX5feQfP0cUBhk7I3WWX0ZD9R5xA9Nn7caOsdaITEk5YaNaa6PVOVeWJc0k7qMRAyoc=</Q><DP>BYKHCuszKaXeyHT173d1QIhf5ZmU1mSY6zM9/D/1oGzJ3DvVIvqcEEkqCGzFqj2nntLu9Ey7U7sque9yyVBIn3KswApDAZurhVw1SZxMbJDiwugj5S9IgrFahGQZEGswZ2gaUC2vGvOlVjDXVPgWXEynaGMY3caizxyacAe0ydk=</DP><DQ>QIPHCClj6F1IS+ceBu6B7ZNf/2yLb4LQs7Rz+jjN91nU4bvEj05tL2bkrRQdKD+FkXJRzygSt4/QRKsEkFz8xMGqignwV7BUl0tJ+wRjH1nw/DV7TS/PRZutZ/CET8FquGrF93jBjSob66PIHlSTwF0+O6MpBUZpx4RW2gOr268=</DQ><InverseQ>QhNl0+iKo25EXw7OMwg0rCalvW2rCr8/+CuXV8swGldRdg/xAYVVnOvervtBqNAnT1wZyi/LY8ajW7daUXCtzHhxkPxJZK/BVyh/hxBLldnlpovryfuFxP9+DFbcxz+Kg7SxkDr9/dGIxy2vjeYwSfeYTwMJq4gOGfsi7abRKoQ=</InverseQ><D>xHk34E6FfUZENE0RA57PZSqH3/W6usz91Ugr1GNtdgs+zdVOeQZ+LDufDh8ewG+szXHDCjL8A0LEldQdK3fLld8FayNWNquhCZdxeOJYnYQi5tD8bXBPXju7lZf37On3pyspOco8QtuYOdWG2Mj/YB0dq5elrqQ0klpGmOnDtGjPxpjXa/WILunSedU1+TNNhYi38tCC+spckCXfoopdCDqJLtb4sB3qroeKQEZ/WS+1p3DUMM4n/KM8M5A8ZMvFTbTTeiT8yasNQBgYW42ZCITUld+8ML6pfQIINKyEByPCjdrLrTGBDS+2LtmabbMB5BnF2adF/r1bRN2Hzx/6PQ==</D></RSAKeyValue>
```

Метод, которым шифрую файл

```
public static void EncryptFile(string file, string password, string KeyRSA)
{ 
// Тут сначала password шифрую RSA_Encrypt
using System.Security.Cryptography.Rfc2898DeriveBytes rfc = new(password, salt, 1000);
 using System.Security.Cryptography.Aes aes = System.Security.Cryptography.Aes.Create();
 aes.Key = bytes.GetBytes(aes.KeySize / 8);
 ...
 // Записываю публичный ключ в файл (на всякий случай для дальнейшего использования)
 using StreamWriter sw = new(newfile);
 sw.Write(KeyRSA);
 sw.Flush();
}
```

А чтобы прочитать шифрованный в base64 ключ из файла использую так:

```
byte[] array = new byte[344]; // 344 длина текста 
fsRead.Read(array, 0, array.Length);
string KeyDec = RSA_Decrypt(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(array), File.ReadAllText("PrivateKey.xml"));
using System.Security.Cryptography.Rfc2898DeriveBytes bytes = new(KeyDec, salt, 1000);
```

Я конечно понимаю что я очень жестко где-то протупил)
Но, пытаясь вникнуть не могу понять что не так(

P.S: Версия DotNet 4.7

Comment: Для шифровки используется публичный, для расшифровки приватный. А вообще для данных ассиметричное шифрование не используют, используют симметричное, например AES. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1445552/373567 Ассиметричное шифрование используют для обмена ключами симметричного.

Comment: @aepot, это я знаю. Мне AES не нужен для шифрования пароля. Задача такая использовать RSA для пароля. И чтобы никто не мог воспользоваться расшифровкой без приватного ключа.

Comment: Приведите пример, как именно тестируете этот код, что содержат XML файлы. Какая версия дотнета? Еще пароль открытый не используют, его хэшируют перед использованием, получается ключ шифрования таким образом.

Comment: А для чаего вы шифруете данные, передаете на другую машину по сети или для локального использования? Что за данные, потеря которых некритична, например куки браузера, или что-то поважнее? Какая операционная система, Windows?

Comment: @aepot, локально. система Windows. Основная задача чтобы нельзя было использовать расшифровку данных без приватного ключа(файла) шифровать хочу пароль и его передавать в зашифрованном виде в файл (на выходе получается Base64 - уже криптованный RSA). Затем на машине пользователя использовать расшифровку приватным ключём (файла)

Comment: Если локально и Windows, то почему не DPAPI тогда? Осталось понять, откуда и куда передавать. DPAPI просто намного проще и надежнее в этом плане. Данные, защищенные с помощью DPAPI невозможно расшифровать нигде кроме как на данной машине или под учеткой конкретного пользователя, который сейчас использует систему (зависит от настроек). Недостаток DPAPI в том, что если систему переустановить, то данные станет вообще невозможно расшифровать, никогда. RSA предназначен для одностороннего обмена данными, в частности от клиента серверу, в обратную сторону используется уже другая пара ключей.

Comment: @aepot, я тоже изначально хотел DPAPI, но задача стоит именно использовать RSA.

Comment: Окей, теперь все понятно, чуть позже гляну код.

Comment: Вставил методы RSA_Encrypt и RSA_Decrypt, создал файлы PublicKey.xml и PrivateKey.xml, пишу `Console.WriteLine(KeyDec);`, выводит в консоль `password`. Что я делаю не так? Выглядит как то, что код работает.

Comment: @aepot, это понятно. Тут проблема с расшифровкой не в одном приложение, а в разных. Создать одно приложение которое шифрует текст и прячет его в файл. Затем создаём отдельное приложение которое загружает приватный ключ и расшифровывает текст. Из одного приложения это работает корректно. Я даже подгрузчик записал. Через FileStream и StreamWriter записываю зашифрованный текст, его же нужно загрузить и расшифровать в другом приложение. Вот задача.

Comment: Кстати `Версия DotNet 4.7` странно, вот это `using RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new(2048);` - код минимум из .NET 5, как-то не сходится. Давайте код полного теста. Работа этого кода не зависит от того, в каком приложении он запущен. Вы можете написать полный цикл шифровки-дешифровки в одном приложении, работать будет точно так же. Вижу, что используете AES для данных, пример как я делал - в первом комментарии, попробуйте код оттуда.

Comment: @aepot, это версия C# меняется в файле `.csproj`. Использую Aes, но это не важно. Тут главная цель записать и прочитать  расшифрованный ключ(пароль).  А уже после использовать тот же самый пароль в Rfc для AES.

Comment: Но ваш код в методах RSA_Encrypt и RSA_Decrypt работает, и чинить там нечего.

Comment: @aepot, вы не понимаете, там где написано "важные строки" если за место `RSA_Decrypt(keyRSA, ...)` делать загрузчик (тоже ниже записан) то данные не расшифровываются.

Comment: Еще догадка, вижу что вы `aes.Key` задаете, а про `aes.IV` вы точно не забыли? Быть может RSA тут вообще не при чем? И снова про как работать с `IV` - ссылка на пример в первом комментарии.

Comment: @aepot, я уже тестировал aes, и нет я не забыл про него) И да я знаю как с ним работать. Проблема точно только в RSA расшифровщике.  Нужно просто понять как правильно расшифровывать данные и передавать в RFC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот пример, шифрования, записи данных в файл, затем чтения и расшифровки.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string encrypted = RSAEncrypt("password", File.ReadAllText("PublicKey.xml"));
    File.WriteAllText("encrypted.txt", encrypted);

    string loaded = File.ReadAllText("encrypted.txt");
    string password = RSADecrypt(loaded, File.ReadAllText("PrivateKey.xml"));
    Console.WriteLine(password);
}

public static string RSAEncrypt(string text, string publicKey)
{
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
    using RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new(2048);
    rsa.FromXmlString(publicKey);
    byte[] encrypted = rsa.Encrypt(bytes, true);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted);
}

public static string RSADecrypt(string base64, string privateKey)
{
    byte[] rgb = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
    using RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new(2048);
    rsa.FromXmlString(privateKey);
    byte[] bytes = rsa.Decrypt(rgb, true);
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
}
```

По сути это тот же ваш код, только аккуратнее написан.

Вывод в консоль

```
password
```

Но я бы советовал двоичные данные хранить как двоичные.

Вот так:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    byte[] encrypted = RSAEncrypt("password", File.ReadAllText("PublicKey.xml"));
    File.WriteAllBytes("encrypted.rsa", encrypted);

    byte[] loaded = File.ReadAllBytes("encrypted.rsa");
    string password = RSADecrypt(loaded, File.ReadAllText("PrivateKey.xml"));
    Console.WriteLine(password);
}

public static byte[] RSAEncrypt(string text, string publicKey)
{
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
    using RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new(2048);
    rsa.FromXmlString(publicKey);
    return rsa.Encrypt(bytes, true);
}

public static string RSADecrypt(byte[] rgb, string privateKey)
{
    using RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new(2048);
    rsa.FromXmlString(privateKey);
    byte[] bytes = rsa.Decrypt(rgb, true);
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
}
```

Вывод в консоль тот же

Comment: Благодарю, попробую когда освобожусь!

Comment: Ваш пример с обычным добавлением в файл работает прекрасно. Но вот я решил попробовать добавить зашифрованный пароль в `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` и присвоить `aes.Key = bytes.GetBytes(aes.KeySize / 8);`  и `aes.IV = bytes.GetBytes(aes.BlockSize / 8);` после записи в файл через `FileStream` добавил двоичные данные зашифрованного пароль (чередует длина между 253 и 255 для загрузки в буффер (через fsRead.Read) так вот на выходе не получается расшифровать файл. Думаю создам отдельную тему и опишу конкретно что не так.

Comment: [Ссылка на тему](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1456230/aes-не-расшифровываются-данные-вместе-с-rfc2898derivebytes)