# AES не расшифровываются данные вместе с Rfc2898DeriveBytes

Tags: c#, rsa, aes, rfc

Пытаюсь добавить в файл шифрованный ключ для RSA [Шифрование RSA ключа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1455697/rsa-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5?noredirect=1#comment2601732_1455697) чтобы потом прочитать его и расшифровать данные.
Но... данные не расшифровываются...

Метод шифрования (AES + RSA) - Ключ-пароль записываю в файл.

```
public static void AES_Encrypt(string inputFile, string outFile)
{
    try
    {
        byte[] salt = new byte[32];
        using (var inputFileStream = new FileStream(inputFile, FileMode.Open))
        using (var outFileStream = new FileStream(outFile, FileMode.Append))
        using (var aes = Aes.Create())
        {
            aes.KeySize = 256;
            aes.BlockSize = 128;
            aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            byte[] encrypted = RSAEncrypt("password", File.ReadAllText("PublicKey.xml"));
            outFileStream.Write(encrypted, 0, encrypted.Length); // Записываю шифрованный пароль в файл
            using (var rfc2898DeriveBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(encrypted, salt, 1000))
            {
                aes.Key = rfc2898DeriveBytes.GetBytes(aes.KeySize / 8);
                aes.IV = rfc2898DeriveBytes.GetBytes(aes.BlockSize / 8);
            }
            using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(outFileStream, aes.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                inputFileStream.CopyTo(cryptoStream);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (CryptographicException ex) { File.AppendAllText("AES_Enc.txt", ex.Message + "\r\n" + ex.ToString()); }
    catch (IOException ex) { File.AppendAllText("AES_Enc_IO.txt", ex.Message + "\r\n" + ex.ToString()); }
    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException) { }
}
```

Пытаюсь расшифровать таким методом:

```
public static byte[] SaltStat = new byte[32];

public static void AES_Decrypt(string encryptedFile, string originalFile)
{
    byte[] salt = new byte[32];
    using (var fsRead = new FileStream(encryptedFile, FileMode.Open))
    using (var outFileStream = new FileStream(originalFile, FileMode.Append))
    using (var aes = Aes.Create())
    {
        aes.KeySize = 256;
        aes.BlockSize = 128;
        aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

        byte[] encrypted_Key = new byte[253];
        fsRead.Read(encrypted_Key, 0, encrypted_Key.Length);

        byte[] decrypted = RSADecrypt(encrypted_Key, File.ReadAllText("PrivateKey.xml"));

        using (var rfc2898DeriveBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(decrypted, salt, 1000))
        {
            aes.Key = rfc2898DeriveBytes.GetBytes(aes.KeySize / 8);
            aes.IV = rfc2898DeriveBytes.GetBytes(aes.BlockSize / 8);
        }
        using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(outFileStream, aes.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read))
        {
            fsRead.CopyTo(cryptoStream);
        }
    }
}
```

У меня 2 вопроса:
1 - Как сделать чтобы если пароль будет разным, то скорее всего и длина разная будет для загрузки (как это зафиксировать и читать столько байтов сколько было записано?
2 - Как собственно правильно расшифровать данные?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сложно тут понять, что надо получить в финале. Во-первых, у вас мешанина в работе с файлами - почему `FileMode.Append`? Это ведь означет дозапись в конец существующего файла. Во-вторых, здесь дыра в безопасности. Ключ шифрования в для AES вы записываете в открытом виде.

Вот в доказательство рабочий код. Мне вообще не потребовалось RSA чтобы расшифровать файл. Испытайте исправление, подумайте, как залатать дыру в безопасности, и если не получится - задайте другой вопрос.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    AESEncrypt("file.txt", "file.aes");
    AESDecrypt("file.aes", "file_out.txt");
}

public static void AESEncrypt(string inputFile, string outFile)
{
    try
    {
        byte[] salt = new byte[32];
        using (var inputFileStream = File.OpenRead(inputFile))
        using (var outFileStream = File.Create(outFile))
        using (var aes = Aes.Create())
        {
            aes.KeySize = 256;
            aes.BlockSize = 128;
            aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            byte[] encrypted = RSAEncrypt("password", File.ReadAllText("PublicKey.xml"));
            outFileStream.Write(encrypted, 0, encrypted.Length);
            using (var rfc2898DeriveBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(encrypted, salt, 1000))
            {
                aes.Key = rfc2898DeriveBytes.GetBytes(aes.KeySize / 8);
                aes.IV = rfc2898DeriveBytes.GetBytes(aes.BlockSize / 8);
            }
            using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(outFileStream, aes.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                inputFileStream.CopyTo(cryptoStream);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); }
}

public static void AESDecrypt(string encryptedFile, string originalFile)
{
    byte[] salt = new byte[32];
    using (var fsRead = File.OpenRead(encryptedFile))
    using (var outFileStream = File.Create(originalFile))
    using (var aes = Aes.Create())
    {
        aes.KeySize = 256;
        aes.BlockSize = 128;
        aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

        byte[] decrypted = new byte[256];
        fsRead.Read(decrypted, 0, decrypted.Length);

        using (var rfc2898DeriveBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(decrypted, salt, 1000))
        {
            aes.Key = rfc2898DeriveBytes.GetBytes(aes.KeySize / 8);
            aes.IV = rfc2898DeriveBytes.GetBytes(aes.BlockSize / 8);
        }
        using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(fsRead, aes.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read))
        {
            cryptoStream.CopyTo(outFileStream);
        }
    }
}

public static byte[] RSAEncrypt(string text, string publicKey)
{
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
    using RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new(2048);
    rsa.FromXmlString(publicKey);
    return rsa.Encrypt(bytes, true);
}

public static byte[] RSADecrypt(byte[] rgb, string privateKey)
{
    using RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new(2048);
    rsa.FromXmlString(privateKey);
    return rsa.Decrypt(rgb, true);
}
```

> Как сделать чтобы если пароль будет разным, то скорее всего и длина разная будет для загрузки (как это зафиксировать и читать столько байтов сколько было записано?

Записать длину массива в тот же поток перед данными

```
int x = 42;
byte[] header = new byte[sizeof(int)]; // 4
BinaryPrimitives.WriteInt32LittleEndian(header, x);
int y = BinaryPrimitives.ReadInt32LittleEndian(header);
```

Как записать массив в поток, вы знаете

---

Ну что, давайте разбираться. Дыра получилась из-за того что вы зачем-то придумали какой-то "пароль" вместо того чтобы шифровать ключ AES с помощью RSA.

- Когда создаете новый AES `Aes.Create()`, он заполняет свой ключ и IV рандомными байтами сам, используя безопасный рандом-генератор, подходящий для создания ключей. Так что ключ, как и IV выдумывать не надо, он будет создан автоматически.
- Далее `KeySize = 256`, `BlockSize = 128`, `Mode = CipherMode.CBC` это значения по умолчанию, я проверил, незачем их явно задавать.
- Рандомный AES вектор дает приятный эффект всегда разного результата при AES-шифровании, зачем упускать такой шанс? Сам по себе IV можно передавать в открытую, знание IV никак не упрощает взлом шифра. Во всяком случае, я не знаю прецендентов, и опытные разработчики соведуют передавать его вместе с данными. Конечно, если включить режим параноика, то можно его так же шифрануть с помощью RSA, никто не запрещает.
- Добавил пример как передавать массив вариативной длины, но в случае с шифрованием 32-байтового ключа, на выходе будет всегда одно и то же по длине.

Затем причесал немного код, получается как-то так:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        RSAEncryptFile("file.txt", "file.aes", File.ReadAllText("PublicKey.xml"));
        RSADecryptFile("file.aes", "file_out.txt", File.ReadAllText("PrivateKey.xml"));
    }
    catch (Exception ex) 
    { 
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); 
    }
}

public static void RSAEncryptFile(string originalFile, string encryptedFile, string publicKey)
{
    using var input = File.OpenRead(originalFile);
    using var output = File.Create(encryptedFile);
    using var aes = Aes.Create();
    output.Write(aes.IV);
    byte[] encryptedAesKey = RSAEncrypt(aes.Key, publicKey);
    byte[] lengthBytes = new byte[sizeof(int)];
    BinaryPrimitives.WriteInt32LittleEndian(lengthBytes, encryptedAesKey.Length);
    output.Write(lengthBytes);
    output.Write(encryptedAesKey);
    using CryptoStream cs = new(output, aes.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
    input.CopyTo(cs);
}

public static void RSADecryptFile(string encryptedFile, string originalFile, string privateKey)
{
    using var input = File.OpenRead(encryptedFile);
    using var output = File.Create(originalFile);
    using var aes = Aes.Create();
    byte[] iv = new byte[aes.BlockSize / 8];
    input.Read(iv);
    aes.IV = iv;
    byte[] lengthBytes = new byte[sizeof(int)];
    input.Read(lengthBytes);
    int length = BinaryPrimitives.ReadInt32LittleEndian(lengthBytes);
    byte[] encryptedAesKey = new byte[length];
    input.Read(encryptedAesKey);
    aes.Key = RSADecrypt(encryptedAesKey, privateKey);
    using CryptoStream cs = new(input, aes.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read);
    cs.CopyTo(output);
}

public static byte[] RSAEncrypt(byte[] data, string publicKey)
{
    using RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new(2048);
    rsa.FromXmlString(publicKey);
    return rsa.Encrypt(data, true);
}

public static byte[] RSADecrypt(byte[] rgb, string privateKey)
{
    using RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new(2048);
    rsa.FromXmlString(privateKey);
    return rsa.Decrypt(rgb, true);
}
```

---

Версия для .NET Framework 4.x (для некромантов)

```
public static void RSAEncryptFile(string originalFile, string encryptedFile, string publicKey)
{
    using (var input = File.OpenRead(originalFile))
    using (var output = File.Create(encryptedFile))
    using (var aes = Aes.Create())
    {
        output.Write(aes.IV, 0, aes.IV.Length);
        byte[] encryptedAesKey = RSAEncrypt(aes.Key, publicKey);
        byte[] lengthBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(encryptedAesKey.Length);
        output.Write(lengthBytes, 0, lengthBytes.Length);
        output.Write(encryptedAesKey, 0, encryptedAesKey.Length);
        using (var cs = new CryptoStream(output, aes.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            input.CopyTo(cs);
        }
    }
}

public static void RSADecryptFile(string encryptedFile, string originalFile, string privateKey)
{
    using (var input = File.OpenRead(encryptedFile))
    using (var output = File.Create(originalFile))
    using (var aes = Aes.Create())
    {
        byte[] iv = new byte[aes.BlockSize / 8];
        input.Read(iv, 0, iv.Length);
        aes.IV = iv;
        byte[] lengthBytes = new byte[sizeof(int)];
        input.Read(lengthBytes, 0, lengthBytes.Length);
        int length = BitConverter.ToInt32(lengthBytes, 0);
        byte[] encryptedAesKey = new byte[length];
        input.Read(encryptedAesKey, 0, encryptedAesKey.Length);
        aes.Key = RSADecrypt(encryptedAesKey, privateKey);
        using (var cs = new CryptoStream(input, aes.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read))
        {
            cs.CopyTo(output);
        }
    }
}

public static byte[] RSAEncrypt(byte[] data, string publicKey)
{
    using (var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048))
    {
        rsa.FromXmlString(publicKey);
        return rsa.Encrypt(data, true);
    }
}

public static byte[] RSADecrypt(byte[] rgb, string privateKey)
{
    using (var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048))
    {
        rsa.FromXmlString(privateKey);
        return rsa.Decrypt(rgb, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Так в том то и прикол записывать в открытом виде, у нас же по сути есть приватный ключ без которого не получится расшифровать данные.  `что надо получить в финале` расшифрованный файл с применением ключа RSA (для пароля) которым расшифровываю данные.

Comment: Записать длину массива в тот же поток перед данными, а `BinaryPrimitives` с какой версии доступен? Мне пока требуется на старом фрейме под 4.7

Comment: `FileMode.Append` - использую для дальнейшей туда дальше записи каких-либо данных (salt. iv и.т.д)

Comment: @ZuPooSwitch я могу дать готовое решение, но завтра, спать пора. А вы пока подумайте, как пофиксить то, что я написал. Вы неправильно поняли суть `FileMode.Append`. Вот есть у вас существующий файл на диске, когда вы его так открываете, новые данные в него дозаписываются в конец. Это не никак не влияет на сам процесс записи. Выше я показал как правильно, с `CryptoStream` тоже напутали, я поправил.

Comment: благодарю, посижу по разбираюсь)  От решения не откажусь. Хоть пойму наконец-то над чем голову столько времени ломал)

Comment: Если я пробую расшифровать подставив `RSADecrypt` - то мне пишет что мол: `ошибка при декодировании заполнения oaep`

Comment: И вот сейчас Ваш пример затестировал, мне пишет что: `Входные данные являются не полным блоком`

Comment: @ZuPooSwitch а какая длина входного файла? Не могу воспроизвести, у меня работает. Чуть позже напишу решение с объяснением.

Comment: работает с ключём RSA ? Мне надо с ним. Длина может быть разная. Сначала я записываю шифрованный пароль `outFileStream.Write(encrypted, 0, encrypted.Length);` его длина разная. Я думаю в этом проблема или же в RFC. Логика, сначала записываем зашифрованный пароль в файл (ключ) затем остальные данные шифрованные файла. В обратную строну пробую прочитать ключ и подставить его в RFC для расшифровки уже остальных данных самого файла. Но не получается.

Comment: @ZuPooSwitch добавил полное решение.

Comment: благодарю за полное решение, буду разбираться. Но, у меня не `Net.Core`а framework. И я так понял по описанию что `BinaryPrimitives.WriteInt32LittleEndian` используется именно там, но не в `.Net Freamework` это же можно заменить на что-нибудь другое?

Comment: @ZuPooSwitch да, можно, есть `BitConverter` https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter?view=netframework-4.8 Странно, что вы в 2022 году используете старый и медленный 4.8. Добавил вариант кода для 4.8 в ответ.

Comment: от души в душу! Я понял в чём допускал ошибки)

Comment: @ZuPooSwitch отлично, рад что все получилось.