C# - Расшифровка Rijndael как в библиотеке DCPCrypt в C++ Builder
В C++ Builder есть простой код для расшифровки
UnicodeString TfmTest::DecryptString(UnicodeString Source, UnicodeString Password)
{
  TDCP_rijndael *DCP_rijndael1;
  DCP_rijndael1 =new TDCP_rijndael(this);   // создаём объект
  DCP_rijndael1->InitStr(Password, __classid(TDCP_sha1)); // инициализируем
  UnicodeString res = DCP_rijndael1->DecryptString(Source); // дешифруем
  DCP_rijndael1->Burn();                            
  DCP_rijndael1->Free();                           
  return res;
}

Как сделать абсолютно такой же в способ расшифровки только в C#? Есть ли какие-либо библиотеки? Все способы, которые я искал в интернете не работают.. Пишет:

System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: "Недопустимая
длина данных для дешифрования."


Во-первых, Rijndael устарел и за его использование в дотнете вам голову отвернут. Во-вторых, в такой формулировке вопрос не имеет ответа. UnicodeString - это именно строка. А должен быть массив байтов. Следовательно, байты до этого были как-то сконвертированы в строковое представление. Как?

Зачем DCP если есть https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rijndael ? И да, Rijndael - дырявое старьё. Вот пример - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1445552/373567, вот ещё пример https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1209370/373567
