# Как зашифровать и расшифровать строку по ключу максимально быстро в C#?

Tags: c#, криптография

Есть строка

```
string text = "Строка для зашифровки";


public string encrypt(string whatToencrypt , string key){}
public string decrypt(string whatToDecrypt , string key){}
```

С помощью каких библиотек C# максимально быстро получится зашифровать и расшифровать затем эту строку?
Главное скорость, а не качество шифрования.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.aes?view=net-7.0 - руководство, точнее полная реализация для Вас

Comment: А это самый быстрый способ изменить строку или есть еще побыстрее?

Comment: Конечно быстрее есть - делать XOR с каждым символом и всё

Comment: то что надо, спасибо!

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1209351/373567

Answer (score 1):

Реализация с XOR:

```
string text = "Строка для зашифровки";


public string encryptDecrypt(string whatToencrypt , string key)
{
       List<byte> resStr = new List<byte>();
       int i = 0;
       foreach (var c in whatToencrypt)
       {
           resStr.Add( (byte)(c ^ key[i++]) );
           i = i % key.Length;
       }
       whatToencrypt = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(resStr.ToArray());
       return whatToencrypt;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Если стойкость шифрования вообще неважна (от слова совсем) – то просто замените каждый символ да хоть через [шифр Цезаря](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80_%D0%A6%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8F). Ещё быстрее – делать просто операцию XOR (исключающее или) с какой-нибудь константой.

Только учтите, что строки в C# - неизменяемый объект. Эффективнее будет создать массив `char[whatToencrypt.Length]`, в него записать зашифрованные символы и уже его собрать в строку с помощью `new string(array)`.