# Ошибка FormatException: The input is not a valid Base-64 string при шифровке текста

Tags: c#, шифрование

Есть класс ключа:

```
public class EncryptKey
{
    public EncryptKey (byte[] key) => Key = key;

    public EncryptKey (string key) => FromString(key);

    public byte[] Key { get; set; }

    public void FromString (string s)
    {
        using SymmetricAlgorithm sa = Aes.Create();

        using Rfc2898DeriveBytes hasher = new(s, sa.IV, 5000, HashAlgorithmName.SHA512);

        Key = hasher.GetBytes(32);
    }

    public override string ToString() => Convert.ToBase64String(Key);
}
```

Реализация шифрования выглядит следующим образом:

```
public static string Encrypt (string text, IEncryptKey key)
{
    string textToEncode = text.Replace("/", "%SL%").Replace("+", "%PL%");

    using Aes aes = Aes.Create();

    aes.Key = key.Key;

    using MemoryStream ms = new();

    ms.Write(aes.IV);

    using (CryptoStream cs = new(ms, aes.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write, true))

        cs.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(textToEncode));

    return Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
}

public static string Decrypt (string text, IEncryptKey key)
{
    string textToDecode = text.Replace("%SL%", "/").Replace("%PL%", "+");

    using MemoryStream ms = new(Convert.FromBase64String(textToDecode));

    byte[] iv = new byte[16];

    _ = ms.Read(iv);

    using Aes aes = Aes.Create();

    aes.Key = key.Key;

    aes.IV = iv;

    using CryptoStream cs = new(ms, aes.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read, true);

    using MemoryStream output = new();

    cs.CopyTo(output);

    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(output.ToArray());
}
```

Вызываю так:

```
var encText = Encrypt(Guid.NewGuid().ToString, new("123"));
var decText = Decrypt(encText, new("123"));
```

В итоге ошибка:

```
FormatException: The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IV не рандомный надо использовать при хэшировании пароля, а один и тот же. То есть какой IV использовали при шифровании, тот же и при расшифровке надо использовать.

Ну и намудрили с классами, к тому же хранить ключ в памяти на постоянке - плохая примета для безопасности. 5000 итерациий - лишяя работа, не добавляющая надежности. Использовать 512-битный хэш для 256-битного ключа - тоже так себе занятие.

Всё хорошо в меру. Никто даже зная соль не сможет расхэшировать пароль даже однократно захэшированный, а 1000 раз перехэшированный и подавно. [RFC 2898](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2898.html) почитайте.

```
private static byte[] KeyFromString(string s, byte[] salt)
{
    using Rfc2898DeriveBytes hasher = new(s, salt, 1000, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256);
    return hasher.GetBytes(32);
}

public static string Encrypt(string text, string password)
{
    using Aes aes = Aes.Create();
    aes.Key = KeyFromString(password, aes.IV);
    using MemoryStream ms = new();
    ms.Write(aes.IV);
    using (CryptoStream cs = new(ms, aes.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write, true))
        cs.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text));
    return Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
}

public static string Decrypt(string base64, string password)
{
    using MemoryStream ms = new(Convert.FromBase64String(base64));
    byte[] iv = new byte[16];
    ms.Read(iv);
    using Aes aes = Aes.Create();
    aes.Key = KeyFromString(password, iv);
    aes.IV = iv;
    using CryptoStream cs = new(ms, aes.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read, true);
    using MemoryStream output = new();
    cs.CopyTo(output);
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(output.ToArray());
}
```

Если вам нужен URL-формат Base64, то можно сконвертировать по стандартам

```
public static string Base64UrlEncode(string base64)
{
    return base64.TrimEnd('=').Replace('+', '-').Replace('/', '_');
}

public static string Base64UrlDecode(string base64)
{
    string result = base64.Replace('_', '/').Replace('-', '+');
    if (result.Length % 4 == 2)
        result += "==";
    else
    if (result.Length % 4 == 3)
        result += "=";
    return result;
}
```

Старайтесь в один метод ненамешивать по много разносортных задач. Метод должен делать что-то одно.

---

```
string text = "Hello World!";
string password = "qwe123";
string base64 = Encrypt(text, password);
Console.WriteLine(base64);
string urlSafeBase64 = Base64UrlEncode(base64);
Console.WriteLine(urlSafeBase64);

string base64decoded = Base64UrlDecode(urlSafeBase64);
string textDecrypted = Decrypt(base64decoded, password);
Console.WriteLine(textDecrypted);
```

Вывод в консоль (каждый раз разный base64 выведет, но так и должно быть)

```
+SslYF2B/sNcZzYZ2f6dGrNMPv0EHgld5+buiAVWyCM=
-SslYF2B_sNcZzYZ2f6dGrNMPv0EHgld5-buiAVWyCM
Hello World!
```

Вот теперь, когда оно заработало, можете уже накручивать на это абстракции, классы и творить прочее ООП. Успехов!

Comment: Спасибо большое. Но увы, всё та же ошибка

Comment: @GoodBoyAlex вы точно всё полностью, как показано скопировали и ничего не изменяли? Когда я запускаю этот код в консоли, он работает. Ошибка говорит о том, что на входе некорректный Base64, вы его либо повредили при передаче, либо забыли декодировать из URL формата.

Comment: Ничего не менял. Просто обернул в статичный класс `StringEncrypt` и использую его в менеджере сессий так; ДОБАВЛЕНИЕ: `string serializedModel = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);string encryptModel = StringEncrypt.Base64UrlEncode(StringEncrypt.Encrypt(serializedModel, encryptKey));return encryptModel;` ПОЛУЧЕНИЕ: `string serializedModel = StringEncrypt.Decrypt(StringEncrypt.Base64UrlDecode(value), encryptKey);return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(serializedModel);`

Comment: @GoodBoyAlex ну и в какой строчке ошибка? Как выглядят данные, которые эту ошибку вызывают? Пошаговую отладку пробовали? Почему вы используете устаревший JSON.NET? В общем я по-всякому прогнал этот код на разных данных разной длины, работает. Убедитесь, что при приеме данных у вас нет ничего лишнего во входной строке. Проблема где-то за пределами этого кода, и если вы не дадите никакой отладочной информации, я не смогу помочь.

Comment: Нашёл, ЧТО происходит. Добавляются лишние кавычки, т.е. если `encryptModel = "XBzUEOp-FlHUshr5gO7ohF49LWLY0QjJmxhZF-7GxanqjLulH7kQX1P3DiYwF4_x_kBqNyaq3crmYNIijT-z7Q" string` , то получал он `"\"XBzUEOp-FlHUshr5gO7ohF49LWLY0QjJmxhZF-7GxanqjLulH7kQX1P3DiYwF4_x_kBqNyaq3crmYNIijT-z7Q\"" string`. Вот теперь надо найти ГДЕ это он лишнее добавляет.

Comment: Проблема решена. Он просто дважды сериализовал строку. Это мой косяк...

Comment: @GoodBoyAlex ура, отладка рулит!